# Java - Pass null reference to a constructor's object and create the instance later

Tags: java, reference

I have to create a "circular list" of object Th.
T0,T1,T2,..,TN-1
Each object own a reference to the one right to it
So T0 has T1 reference .... and TN-1 has T0 reference.

```
class Th
{
    private Th nextTh;
    Th(Th n) {
        nextTh=Th;
    }
}
```

In the main method i do this

```
 Th[] th = new Th[N]; //Create the references
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     th[i]= new Th(th[(i+1)%(N)],first,shared,i,N,counter);
```

As you can see, when i=0 in the for loop I create the new Object Th and in the constructor I pass the argument `th[i+1]` (so `th[1]`) that in the moment is a reference to a null object, but I create it in the next step i=1.
In fact, when inside the Th class I reference to nextTh, and I get `NullPointerException`.

```
class Th {
     ....
    doSomething() {
        nextTh.foo(); //Throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

I know that Java is passing parameters just by value, from primitives it makes a copy and for Object it passes "the copy of the reference (right?).

Thank you.

Comment: No. It passes the value of the reference. And `null` isn't going to become a valid reference later. `null` is a special type. The null type.

Comment: Yeah i meant it passes the copy of the reference, like the copy of the pointer. I got that null is a special type. Thank you

Comment: what is the purpose of the Th class?

Comment: It is a Thread. I solved making a setter void addNeighbour(Th) ! Thank you.
I tought that th[x] is a referenence and it could be passed even if it referenced to a null object.

Answer (score 0):

write your main method like below

```
    // N = 30, just for testing
    final int N = 30;
    Th[] thArr = new Th[N];

    // first element
    Th th0 = new Th(null, 0);
    // initialize first element into array
    thArr[0] = th0;
    // general element
    Th thNext;

    // loop
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        thNext = new Th(null, i);
        thArr[i - 1].nextTh = thNext;
        thArr[i] = thNext;
    }
    // setting next element of last element to first element
    thArr[N - 1].setNextTh(th0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what does the `Th(th[(i+1)%(N)],first,shared,i,N,counter)`, but since it throws a `NullPointerException` when passed a `null` as the first argument, you cannot use it at least for one of the `Th` instances.

I suggest you create the first `Th` instance with the `Th(Th n)` constructor, passing `null` to it:

```
th[0] = new Th(null);
```

Then you can create the other instances in reverse order:

```
for (int i = N - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    th[i] = new Th(th[(i+1)%(N)],first,shared,i,N,counter); 
}
```

Finally, modify `th[0]`:

```
th[0].setNext(th[1]);
```

This will close the cycle.